# How to resample daily data to hourly data for all whole days with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe df like the one below:

```
    city    datetime    value
0   city_a  2020-07-10  2
1   city_a  2020-07-11  5
2   city_b  2020-07-11  4
```

And I am trying to resample the daily datetimes with a 6h frequency (data every 00h, 6h, 12h and 18h).

The following code gives me almost the output I am expecting

```
my_df = my_df.set_index(['datetime', 'city'])
my_df = my_df.unstack(-1).resample('6H').pad()
my_df = my_df.stack().reset_index()
my_df = my_df[['city', 'datetime', 'value']]
my_df = my_df.sort_values(['city', 'datetime'])
```

Output:

```
    city    datetime            value
0   city_a  2020-07-10 00:00:00 2.0
1   city_a  2020-07-10 06:00:00 2.0
2   city_a  2020-07-10 12:00:00 2.0
3   city_a  2020-07-10 18:00:00 2.0
4   city_a  2020-07-11 00:00:00 5.0
5   city_b  2020-07-11 00:00:00 4.0
```

However, we can see that the day 2020-07-11 is not complete. I would like the rows including 2020-07-11 06:00:00, 12:00:00 and 18:00:00 to appear into the output.

So my expected output should be:

```
    city    datetime            value
0   city_a  2020-07-10 00:00:00 2.0
1   city_a  2020-07-10 06:00:00 2.0
2   city_a  2020-07-10 12:00:00 2.0
3   city_a  2020-07-10 18:00:00 2.0
4   city_a  2020-07-11 00:00:00 5.0
6   city_a  2020-07-11 06:00:00 5.0
8   city_a  2020-07-11 12:00:00 5.0
10  city_a  2020-07-11 18:00:00 5.0
5   city_b  2020-07-11 00:00:00 4.0
7   city_b  2020-07-11 06:00:00 4.0
9   city_b  2020-07-11 12:00:00 4.0
11  city_b  2020-07-11 18:00:00 4.0
```

Is there an elegant way to do it with Pandas ?

---

Code to generate the dataframe:

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame(data = {
    'city': ['city_a', 'city_a', 'city_b'],
    'datetime': 
[pd.to_datetime('2020/07/10'),pd.to_datetime('2020/07/11'),pd.to_datetime('2020/07/11')],
    'value': [2,5,4]
})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Use**:

```
# STEP A
df1 = (df.groupby('city')['datetime'].max() + pd.Timedelta(days=1)).reset_index()

# STEP B
df1 = pd.concat([df, df1]).set_index('datetime')

# STEP C
df1 = df1.groupby('city', as_index=False).resample('6H').ffill()

# STEP D
df1 = df1.reset_index().drop('level_0', 1).dropna(subset=['value'])
```

**Details:**

STEP A: Use [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group the dataframe on `city` to determine the maximum value of date in each group and add `1 day` to max value of every group, this will be needed for resampling the dataframe.

```
# print(df1)
     city   datetime
0  city_a 2020-07-12
1  city_b 2020-07-12
```

STEP B: Using [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to concat the original dataframe `df` to the newly created dataframe `df1`, this is because we have to resample the dataframe in STEP C.

```
# print(df1)
              city  value
datetime                 
2020-07-10  city_a    2.0
2020-07-11  city_a    5.0
2020-07-11  city_b    4.0
2020-07-12  city_a    NaN
2020-07-12  city_b    NaN
```

STEP C: Using [`DataFrame.resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) resample the dataframe grouped on `city` with a frequency of `6H` and use `ffill` to forward fill the values.

```
# print(df1)
                         city  value
  datetime                          
0 2020-07-10 00:00:00  city_a    2.0
  2020-07-10 06:00:00  city_a    2.0
  2020-07-10 12:00:00  city_a    2.0
  2020-07-10 18:00:00  city_a    2.0
  2020-07-11 00:00:00  city_a    5.0
  2020-07-11 06:00:00  city_a    5.0
  2020-07-11 12:00:00  city_a    5.0
  2020-07-11 18:00:00  city_a    5.0
  2020-07-12 00:00:00  city_a    NaN
1 2020-07-11 00:00:00  city_b    4.0
  2020-07-11 06:00:00  city_b    4.0
  2020-07-11 12:00:00  city_b    4.0
  2020-07-11 18:00:00  city_b    4.0
  2020-07-12 00:00:00  city_b    NaN
```

STEP D: Finally use [`DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and drop the unused columns using [`DataFrame.drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) along `axis=1`, also use [`DataFrame.dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) to drop the rows with `NaN` values in column `value`.

```
# print(df1)
              datetime    city  value
0  2020-07-10 00:00:00  city_a    2.0
1  2020-07-10 06:00:00  city_a    2.0
2  2020-07-10 12:00:00  city_a    2.0
3  2020-07-10 18:00:00  city_a    2.0
4  2020-07-11 00:00:00  city_a    5.0
5  2020-07-11 06:00:00  city_a    5.0
6  2020-07-11 12:00:00  city_a    5.0
7  2020-07-11 18:00:00  city_a    5.0
9  2020-07-11 00:00:00  city_b    4.0
10 2020-07-11 06:00:00  city_b    4.0
11 2020-07-11 12:00:00  city_b    4.0
12 2020-07-11 18:00:00  city_b    4.0
```

Comment: @Shubham Sharma, thank you ! This is what I was looking for ! As jezrael said, some explanations would be welcomed though

Comment: @yoyoog please consider my answer as well, it may be easier to understand and yet it gives the exact expected output :)

Comment: Super, now it is nice ;)

Answer (score 5):

The only way I see is to add a empty row, having a datetime equal to the latest existing datetime + one day. Then you can nearly do exactly the same (pivot is a handy way to replace set_index and unstack).

```py
# adding a row where datetime corresponds to the max datetime + 1 day
df.loc[len(df), 'datetime'] = df.datetime.max() + pd.Timedelta(days=1)

# pivot to replace set_index & unstack
df = (df.pivot(index='datetime', columns='city')
   .resample('6H')
   .pad(3)
   .stack()
   .reset_index()
   .sort_values(['city', 'datetime']))

df[['city', 'datetime', 'value']]

    city    datetime    value
0   city_a  2020-07-10 00:00:00 2.0
1   city_a  2020-07-10 06:00:00 2.0
2   city_a  2020-07-10 12:00:00 2.0
3   city_a  2020-07-10 18:00:00 2.0
4   city_a  2020-07-11 00:00:00 5.0
6   city_a  2020-07-11 06:00:00 5.0
8   city_a  2020-07-11 12:00:00 5.0
10  city_a  2020-07-11 18:00:00 5.0
5   city_b  2020-07-11 00:00:00 4.0
7   city_b  2020-07-11 06:00:00 4.0
9   city_b  2020-07-11 12:00:00 4.0
11  city_b  2020-07-11 18:00:00 4.0
```

Comment: You are considering the max value for the whole datetime column, but i think we have to consider the max value of datetime by group.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Yes you are right, my example was quite misleading because max date was same for both group, but it might be different

Comment: I've tested the code and when for example we in `df` change `city_b` date to `2020-07-13` then in result we have records `city_a` with date `2020-07-12` which is not correct. Maybe max date should be added per group.

Comment: @ShubhamSharma @yoyoog check how the pivot looks like, you will see that it includes all dates in `datetime`.
@ipj This behaviour is caused by the `pad` function.I edited by setting a limit of 3, we ensure that no more than 3 next rows are filled (wich corresponds to 6, 12 and 18h)

Comment: Now after changing to `.pad(3)` and in `df` changing `city_b` date to `2020-07-13` there is no records every 6H in `city_b` :-)

Comment: @ipj This is weird, I tried what you just wrote and it works as expected on my side